# Loop PHP code to INSERT a specific number of unique rows to MySQL

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

Having a bit of trouble with a PHP & MySql script I'm trying to create. It's a bit complex so hope a guru out there can take a stab.

I need to generate 100 random 8 digit numbers and insert them as new rows into a MySQL table. The numbers have to be unique (i.e. not already in the column) and I need to make sure that I create exactly 100 rows - the problem being that if the 8 digit number is already in the column, existing solutions that suggest INSERT IGNORE etc will just skip over a row so I would end up only adding eg. 98 rows if 2 rows already contain the number.

So far I have gotten to a point where I can generate a random number (within limits), check the DB for that number in the specified column, if it doesn't exist it creates a new row. Concurrently the unique number is used to generate and save a QR code - the ultimate goal being to simply run the script once to create 100 QR codes and store their info in the DB.

So far I can do it for one number - any ideas on the best way to loop this?

```
<?php

// Connection variables:
$hostname="mydbhost";
$user="user";
$pass="password";
$dbname="name";

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$pass,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Pull the data from the DB
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT number FROM qrcodes");

$data=array();

// Fill array with the data from the DB
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data [] = $row[0];

}
//Min & Max values for the random numbers
$min = 80000000;
$max = 80009999;

//Set content to be included in QR Code and Label
$qrcontent = rand($min,$max);


if(in_array("$qrcontent", $data))
{
    //echo "Error: It's already in the DB!";
}
else
{
    //When not in the database
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO qrcodes (id, number, status) VALUES ('', '$qrcontent', '0')");

// the rest of the else clause creates and saves the QR code - just included it for interest sake
$text = "$qrcontent"; // URL for code to 
$label = "$qrcontent"; // message to display below barcode


//google chart API URL
// $image = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=190x190&chl=" . $text . "&chld=h";
$image = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=190x190&chl=" . $text . "&chld=h|2";

//Set path to font file to be used for label
$font = '/include/fonts/arialbd.ttf';

//Get the QR code image from google
$background = imagecreatefrompng($image); 
$swidth = imagesx($background); 
$sheight = imagesy($background); 

//If label field isn't blank, draw it in below the code
if(isset($label))
{
    $font_color = imagecolorallocate($background, 0, 0, 0); // set font color
    if(strlen($label) >= 15)
    {
        //split string in two, down the middle
        $half = (int) ( (strlen($label) / 2) ); // cast to int incase str length is odd
        $left = trim(substr($label, 0, $half));
        $right = trim(substr($label, $half));

        // Write Text
        imagettftext($background, 10, 0, 58, 181, $font_color, $font, $left);
        imagettftext($background, 10, 0, 58, 190, $font_color, $font, $right);
    } else {
        // Write Text
        imagettftext($background, 12, 0, 58, 190, $font_color, $font, $label);
    }
}


// Output header and final image 
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=" . $image); 
// Save image to specified file
imagepng($background, "/var/www/images/qrcodes/".$qrcontent.".png"); 
// Optional - print image to screen in browser too
imagepng($background);


// Destroy the images 
imagedestroy($background); 

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Appreciate any insight

Comment: Why do you want the numbers to be "random"?

Comment: Just an extra layer of security really

Comment: All you want to do is prevent users from seeing a number in the URL and changing it just to see what happens? I'd suggest just doing some quick math on the database ID field when generating the codes, e.g. multiply it by 7, subtract 5, and then base64_encode it. Do the reverse on the page you display. `$id=25; echo base64_encode(($id * 7) - 5); \\prints "MTcw"`

Comment: Note that this does not provide security, but does provide more obscurity than your proposed method, and much lighter on the DB side.

Comment: That's a handy little trick - will keep it in mind. This is just to deter random punters guessing a number to use our application in the real world - but it's unlikely and there are more security layers in any case. Cheers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of irrelevant code above, but the gist of what you want is to use a UNIQUE key on the `number` column and code like this:

```
// your connection code ....

// How many rows inserted so far?
$rows_inserted = 0;
$numbers_inserted = array();

// Loop until done
while($rows_inserted < 100) {
    // Create random number
    //Set content to be included in QR Code and Label
    $qrcontent = rand($min,$max);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO qrcodes (id, number, status) VALUES ('', '$qrcontent', '0')");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {
        $rows_inserted++;  // update the counter
        mysqli_affected_rows($con);
        // All your image manipulation code and so on ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ed, that worked like a charm. Logic & code works perfectly.

Comment: For anyone who might be facing the same issue in the future - to change a column in a database to be a UNIQUE value use - ALTER TABLE "tablename" ADD UNIQUE ("columnname")

Comment: Ed, after some testing I've realised that although this code will generate 100 numbers and only leave 1 instance of each in the DB, if it generates a number that is already in the database, it will just skip entering a new row, leaving the original. Ideally, it would check the DB for a number, if there already there it will create a new one - this way, I will always end up with 100 extra unique rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... It should enter 100 rows, no matter what; that's what the mysqli_affected_rows is for. Try replacing that line with `if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 1) {`.

Comment: Ed - I've noticed an error after a few days of testing. When I run the code above it executes and all the QR images are generated. However, the loop is not inserting some items into the database. E.g I ran this to insert 1900 rows, but it only inserted  1184. I tried to run the code to insert a single entry that should have been created but  it enters a continuous loop - as if the PHP code is recognising the entry in the database and trying to skip to the next number (it can't as I've limited it), however the number isn't actually in the DB - any further ideas to hopefully tie this up?

Comment: PS. I tried entering the missing single row directly into the DB and it goes in that way

Comment: Are you sure it's not a unique key collision? It sounds like one. Please verify that the number of rows in the table actually changes when you do a manual insert. In your code above, the range between `$min` and `$max` is only 9,999, so there are only 10,000 possible numbers. If you are inserting 1900+, you are probably starting to get a large number of collisions.

Comment: I've done is double checked the DB, and the primary key (id) is set to Auto Increment. I'm trying to distil the problem so trying to insert 1 row with a value of 80005007. I removed the id column & value from the insert statement code above (as it should set itself) but it's still not working. However, when I run the sql statement directly into the DB it does insert the row

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow. So, 80005007 isn't in the database, but you can't insert it using PHP? That sounds like a different enough problem to deserve its own question so it gets attention. You might consider asking a new question with the latest version of your code.

Comment: Ed - actually you were right above - it was an error regarding a unique key collision. I reset the unique key in the DB (set to NN & AI), changed the SQL statement to read: "INSERT INTO qrcodes (id, number, status) VALUES (NOT NULL, '".$number."', '0')" and it fixed the problem. I had forgot to update a DB connection parameter which is why it didn't work immediately. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors at play here:

How often do you want to repeat the process? At some point in time, your 8 digits will be exhausted and also, 8 digits could be relatively easy to guess.

Do the numbers have to be truly random? Think about adding digits or alphanumeric characters.

These things aside, you want to do the following:

1. SELECT all existing QR-codes from the database
2. Create a new number in a loop:

   ```
   do {
       $random = myRandomNumberGenerator();
   } while (!in_array($random, $existingNumbers) && !in_array($random, $newNumbers));
   ```

   You probably want to set a limit to prevent infinite loops. This way, you don't fail if there's a duplicate.
3. Repeat this process 100 times and put all new numbers in an array `$newNumbers`
4. Turn your entire array into a single SQL statement.

   ```
   foreach ($newNumbers as $new) {
       $str .= "('', '$new', '0'),";
   }
   ```

And finally build and execute the query:

```
"INSERT INTO (id, number, status) VALUES " . $str;
```

Comment: `8 digits could be relatively easy to guess` - really? I'm thinking of a number between 10,000,000 (ten million) and 99,999,999 (ninetynine thousand nine hundred and ninetynine), i'll give you 1 million guesses :) Basically I think it's not true. Yes if he needs close to that many million records then unique random numbers won't be suitable but other than that it's fine

Comment: Well, not guessable by a human being, but if you write a script that iterates between 10,000,000 and 99,999,999, it all depends on the capability of the machine/network/whatever circumstances :)

Comment: Thanks ntaso, that's exactly what I was thinking, just wasn't sure how to do it. This would work - Ed's answer above is pretty elegant though and takes much of the strain off the database, particularly when iterating a vast number of times.

Comment: Fine with me, but just a small note: My code has 2 queries in total, Ed's answer has 100 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just generating the random numbers:

```
$picked = array();
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qrcode");
for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result2);$i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $picked[] = $row['number'];
}
$randomn = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $n = 00000000;
    while(in_array($n,$randomn) || in_array($n,$picked)) {
        $n = mt_rand($min,$max);
    }
    $randomn[] = $n;
}
```

Then use the $randomn array to get all the random numbers.